# Operator on continuous functions, its norm is not attained

Tags: functional-analysis, definite-integrals, normed-spaces

Prove that the norm of this linear functional :

$$\phi: \mathcal{C} ([0,1]) \ni f \rightarrow \int_0 ^{1/2} f(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f(t)dt \in \mathbb{K} $$

equals $1$ if $\mathcal{C} ([0,1])$ is equipped with the supremum norm

but there does not exist $f \in \mathcal{C} ([0,1])$ such that $||f|| \le 1$ and $| \phi (f) | = 1$

What happens if we equip $\mathcal{C} ([0,1])$ with $L^1$ norm?

Using mean value theorem for integrals, it is easy to show that $|| \phi || \le 1$

Now, would it suffice to construct a sequence of functions:

$f_n (\frac{1}{2}) = 4$ and we draw a straight line from the point $(0,0)$ to $(\frac{1}{2},4)$ and a straight line from $(\frac{1}{2},4)$ to $(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}, 0)$
and $f_n (x) = 0$ for $x \in [\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}, 1]$?

Then $\int_0 ^{1/2} f_n(t)dt - \int_{1/2}^1 f_n(t)dt \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, wouldn't it?

How can one show that there doesn't exists $f$ for which the norm is attained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** For the first question, I'd consider the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of continuous functions where $$\begin{eqnarray}
  f_n(x)&= 1 &&\text{for }x \in \left[0,\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{1}{n}\right], \\
  f_n(x)&= -1 &&\text{for }x \in \left[\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{n},1\right],
\end{eqnarray}$$
and where $f_n(x)$ forms a straight line from $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{1}{n},1\right)$ to $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{n},-1\right)$ on the "in-between" interval $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)$.

Then $\|f_n\| = 1$ and $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f = -\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2n}$, therefore $\phi(f_n) = 1 - \tfrac{1}{n}$, and thus $$
  \|\phi\| = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1])} \frac{\left|\phi(f)\right|}{\|f\|} \geq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left|\phi(f_n)\right|}{\|f_n\|} = 1.
$$
For an upper bound on $\|\phi\|$, I'd use that $\left|\int_a^b f\right| \leq (b-a)\|f\|$, which yields for arbitrary $f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ that $$
  \|\phi\| = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1])} \frac{\left|\phi(f)\right|}{\|f\|} \leq \sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}([0,1])} \frac{\tfrac{1}{2}\|f\| + \tfrac{1}{2}\|f\|}{\|f\|}  = 1.
$$
Taken together, this shows that $\|\phi\| = 1$.

**2)** For the second question, take an arbitrary $f$ with $\|f\| = 1$. We already know (from $\left|\int_a^b f\right| \leq (b-a)\|f\|$) that $$
  -\frac{1}{2} \leq \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f \leq \frac{1}{2}, \qquad
   -\frac{1}{2} \leq \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f \leq \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Therefore, to have $\phi(f) = 1$, $f$ would need to satisfy $\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} f = -\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 f = \tfrac{1}{2}$. Since $f$ is continuous, and since $\left|f(x)\right|$ is bounded by $1$, this requires that $f$ is identically $1$ on $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$, and identically $-1$ on $\left(\frac{1}{2},1\right]$. But this is impossible for a continuous $f$.